# terminating filters in a list using RegEx

Tags: regex, list, google-analytics, qregularexpression

Our site has more than 20K pages, each with a distinct ID in the URL that allows us to identify who was visited. We want to run a comparison. However, using regular expression, I cannot narrow my filter to a specific list of sites, because the permutations of each list item are also returned. For example:

If I have the following filter: **Include > Page > Regex > (748|1419|1496)** I get every permutation of 748, including 9**748**, **748**2, **748**3, etc. This creates a problem because I am limited only to my first 5000 results, so I will lose some of those I need to accurately complete my report.

[example of filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBAGy.jpg)

[example of return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cEYb.jpg)

Comment: You may try `(^|\D)(748|1419|1496)(\D|$)` if you want to only match these exact digits not enclosed with other digits.

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thanks @stribizhev !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only match exactly `748`, `1419`, and `1496` as whole numbers not enclosed with other digits, you may use

```
(^|\D)(748|1419|1496)(\D|$)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dH0zA1/2)

The `\D` shorthand class matches a non-digit symbol, `^` is a start-of-string anchor, and `$` asserts the position at the end of the string.